# How can you enable SMB2.0 on a router running DD-WRT?

Tags: networking, network-shares, samba, dd-wrt, smb

I think the steps are something like:

1. Install DD-WRT on a router with an external hard-drive
2. [Install Optware](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Optware,_the_Right_Way) to get Samba
3. [Upgrade to Samba 3.6](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Samba3) (the link shows Samba 3.5, but using the [NSLU2 optware packages](http://www.nslu2-linux.org/wiki/Optware/Packages), you can get 3.6 with built-in SMB2.0)
4. Enable SMB2 in samba.conf
5. Restart
6. ...then a miracle occurs...
7. Then you can use SMB2.0 to connect to your share

What is step 6? I can't find it on forums, etc.

Am using Microsoft Network monitor to check for SMB2.0 connection, I'm on Windows 7 and have tried network connections on wireless and gigabit wired to the router. No joy.

I doubt it matters, but to get ahead of the questions: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (10/26/10) big
(SVN revision 15508M NEWD-2 K2.6 Eko) on Cisco/Linksys E3000